# Flutter, slider_button

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I am trying to create a draggable button to be able to accept or deny requests, I have used the Dtaggable Widget but it is giving me many problems, the last one is to limit the Dragable(button) to the container and therefore I've seen Dragabble is not designed for this and I should have used GestureDetector instead, but when I tried, I can't position the button in the center and let me take the distances well, if someone could give me a hand I would appreciate it.

```
class SliderButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final double containerWidth;
  final double containerHeight;
  final Color containerColor;

  final double buttonSize;
  final Color buttonColor;

  final Color textColor;
  final double textSize;

  final String leftText;
  final String rightText;

  final String textResultDeny;
  final String textResultAccept;

  final IconData icon;
  final Color iconColor;

  final Function(BuildContext context)? sliderPrimaryFunction;
  final Function(BuildContext context)? sliderSecondaryFunction;

  SliderButton(
      {required this.containerWidth,
      required this.containerHeight,
      this.containerColor = Colors.black,
      this.buttonSize = 50,
      this.buttonColor = Colors.white,
      this.rightText = 'Aceptar',
      this.textResultAccept = 'Aceptado',
      this.leftText = 'Denegar',
      this.textResultDeny = 'Denegado',
      this.sliderPrimaryFunction,
      this.sliderSecondaryFunction,
      this.textColor = Colors.white,
      this.textSize = 24,
      this.icon = Icons.add_circle_outline,
      this.iconColor = Colors.black});

  @override
  _SliderButtonState createState() => _SliderButtonState();
}

class _SliderButtonState extends State<SliderButton> {
  Offset position = Offset(0, 0);
  bool started = false;
  int switchOptions = 0;
  Color? _containerColor = Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: sliderContainer(),
    );
  }

  sliderContainer() => Container(
      width: this.widget.containerWidth,
      height: this.widget.containerHeight,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.00),
        color: _containerColor,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black,
            offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0),
            blurRadius: 6.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: sliderContainerContent());

  sliderContainerContent() {
    if (switchOptions == 0) return Center(child: containerContent());
    if (switchOptions == 1)
      return textResult(this.widget.textResultAccept);
    else if (switchOptions == 2) return textResult(this.widget.textResultDeny);
  }

  containerContent() => Container(
    width: this.widget.containerWidth,
    height: this.widget.containerHeight,
    child: Row(
          children: [
            started == false
                ? primaryText(this.widget.leftText, Alignment.centerLeft)
                : Container(),
            Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: Draggable(
                    axis: Axis.horizontal,
                    feedback: roundedButton(),
                    child: started == false ? roundedButton() : Container(),
                    onDragStarted: () => setState(() {
                      started = true;
                    }),
                    onDragUpdate: (details) => _sequentialColor(details),
                    onDragEnd: (details) => _onSlideDragUpdate(details),
                  ),
                ),
            ),
            started == false
                ? primaryText(this.widget.rightText, Alignment.centerRight)
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
  );

  roundedButton() => Align(
        child: Container(
          width: this.widget.buttonSize,
          height: this.widget.buttonSize,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: this.widget.buttonColor,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0),
                blurRadius: 6.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Icon(this.widget.icon,
              color: this.widget.iconColor, size: this.widget.buttonSize),
        ),
      );

  primaryText(String text, Alignment alignment) => Container(
        alignment: alignment,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
        child: Text(text,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .headline5
                ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
      );

  textResult(String text) => Center(
      child: Text(text,
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline3
              ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white)));

  void _sequentialColor(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    print(details.localPosition.dx);
    var initColor = 200;
    var algo = 240;
    var algo2 = 200;
    for (var i = details.localPosition.dx; i > algo; i++) {
      setState(() {
        _containerColor = Colors.green[initColor];
        initColor += 100;
        algo += 30;
      });
    }
    for (var i = details.localPosition.dx; i < algo2; i--) {
      setState(() {
        _containerColor = Colors.red[initColor];
        initColor += 100;
        algo2 -= 30;
      });
    }
  }

  void _onSlideDragUpdate(DraggableDetails details) {
    if (details.offset.distance > 470) {
      setState(() {
        switchOptions = 1;
        _containerColor = Colors.lightGreen;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
          this.widget.sliderPrimaryFunction ?? Navigator.pop(context);
        });
      });
    } else if (details.offset.distance < 400) {
      setState(() {
        switchOptions = 2;
        _containerColor = Theme.of(context).errorColor;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
          this.widget.sliderPrimaryFunction ?? Navigator.pop(context);
        });
      });
    } else
      setState(() {
        _containerColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark;
        started = false;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in this package.
https://pub.dev/packages/slider_button
Here is an example for you for the plugin. If you are having issue regarding the package. I will be happy to help you configure your own code

```
Center(child: SliderButton(
      action: () {
        ///Do something here
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
       label: Text(
          "Slide to cancel Event",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff4a4a4a), fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 17),
        ),
      icon: Text(
        "x",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          fontSize: 44,
        ),
      ),


    ));
```

Comment: Thank you very much found my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the reply. I was trying to do it without the help of external packages, I ended up changing the Draggable for GestureDetector and it already works correctly.
Here I leave my solution in case it could be of help to someone.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SliderButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<double> valueChanged;

  final double containerWidth;
  final double containerHeight;
  final Color containerColor;

  final double buttonSize;
  final Color buttonColor;

  final Color textColor;
  final double textSize;

  final String leftText;
  final String rightText;

  final String textResultDeny;
  final String textResultAccept;

  final IconData icon;
  final Color iconColor;

  final Function(BuildContext context)? sliderPrimaryFunction;
  final Function(BuildContext context)? sliderSecondaryFunction;

  SliderButton({
    required this.valueChanged,
    required this.containerWidth,
    required this.containerHeight,
    this.containerColor = Colors.black,
    this.buttonSize = 50,
    this.buttonColor = Colors.white,
    this.rightText = 'Aceptar',
    this.textResultAccept = 'Aceptado',
    this.leftText = 'Denegar',
    this.textResultDeny = 'Denegado',
    this.sliderPrimaryFunction,
    this.sliderSecondaryFunction,
    this.textColor = Colors.white,
    this.textSize = 24,
    this.icon = Icons.add_circle_outline,
    this.iconColor = Colors.black,
  });

  @override
  _SliderButtonState createState() => _SliderButtonState();
}

class _SliderButtonState extends State<SliderButton> {
  ValueNotifier<double> valueListener = ValueNotifier(.0);
  bool started = false;
  int switchOptions = 0;
  Color? _containerColor = Colors.black;
  IconData _icon = Icons.lock;

  @override
  void initState() {
    valueListener.addListener(notifyParent);
    valueListener.value = 0.5;
    super.initState();
  }

  void notifyParent() {
    this.widget.valueChanged(valueListener.value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: sliderContainer(),
    );
  }

  sliderContainer() => Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: this.widget.containerWidth,
            height: this.widget.containerHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.00),
              color: _containerColor,
            ),
            child: sliderContainerContent(),
          ),
          Positioned(bottom: 2, child: slider())
        ],
      );

  sliderContainerContent() {
    if (switchOptions == 0) return Center(child: containerContent());
    if (switchOptions == 1)
      return textResult(this.widget.textResultAccept);
    else if (switchOptions == 2) return textResult(this.widget.textResultDeny);
  }

  containerContent() => Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          started == false ? primaryText(this.widget.leftText) : Container(),
          started == false ? primaryText(this.widget.rightText) : Container(),
        ],
      );

  primaryText(String text) => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
        child: Text(text,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .headline5
                ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
      );

  textResult(String text) => Center(
      child: Text(text,
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline3
              ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white)));

  slider() => Container(
        width: this.widget.containerWidth,
        height: this.widget.containerHeight,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.00),
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            final handle = gestureDetector();
            return animatedBuilder(handle);
          },
        ),
      );

  gestureDetector() => GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: _slideColor,
        onHorizontalDragStart: (details) {
          setState(() {
            started = true;
          });
        },
        onHorizontalDragEnd: _onSlideDragUpdate,
        child: roundedButton(),
      );

  animatedBuilder(handle) => AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: valueListener,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return AnimatedAlign(
            duration:
                Duration(milliseconds: valueListener.value == 0.5 ? 300 : 0),
            alignment: Alignment(valueListener.value * 2 - 1, .5),
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child: handle,
      );

  roundedButton() => Container(
        width: this.widget.buttonSize,
        height: this.widget.buttonSize,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: this.widget.buttonColor,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey,
              offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0),
              blurRadius: 6.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Icon(_icon,
            color: this.widget.iconColor, size: this.widget.buttonSize - 5),
      );

  void _slideColor(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    valueListener.value =
        (valueListener.value + details.delta.dx / this.widget.containerWidth)
            .clamp(.0, 1.0);

    var sliderColor = 200;
    var slideRight = 0.5;
    var slideLeft = 0.5;
    var i = valueListener.value;
    for (; i > slideRight;) {
      setState(() {
        this._containerColor = Colors.green[sliderColor];
        sliderColor += 100;
        slideRight += 0.1;
        _icon = Icons.lock_open_sharp;
      });
    }
    for (; i < slideLeft;) {
      setState(() {
        this._containerColor = Colors.red[sliderColor];
        sliderColor += 100;
        slideLeft -= 0.1;
        _icon = Icons.lock_outline_sharp;
      });
    }
  }

  void _onSlideDragUpdate(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (valueListener.value >= 0.9) {
      valueListener.value = 1;
      setState(() {
        switchOptions = 1;
        _containerColor = Colors.lightGreen;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
          this.widget.sliderPrimaryFunction ?? Navigator.pop(context);
        });
      });
    } else if (valueListener.value <= 0.1) {
      valueListener.value = 0;
      setState(() {
        switchOptions = 2;
        _containerColor = Theme.of(context).errorColor;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
          this.widget.sliderPrimaryFunction ?? Navigator.pop(context);
        });
      });
    } else {
      valueListener.value = 0.5;
      setState(() {
        _containerColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark;
        _icon = Icons.lock;
        started = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

'''

it still needs some improves but its working.